# Wordpress - Hide a page when a user try to navigate to it writing the URL

Tags: wordpress, url

Example: I created a custom post type "movie". I added links of some movie posts in the nav menu, and it's ok if a user navigates to a post writing in the browser the URL (like `www.site.com/movie/apocalypse-now`) but I don't want that the user navigates to the page `www.site.com/movie` (that lists all the movies).
Is there a way to hide that page?

Comment: do you want to disable the post type archive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not register **has_archive** to **false** in your [register_post_type() function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)?

Would be a solution if you want to disable the post type archive.

Comment: yes, that was a great idea but it doesn't work! I set `'has_archive'   => false,` for the movie post type but if I go to www.site.com/movie it shows! why?

Comment: Have you tried flushing your rewrite rules? Go to **Settings -> Permalinks** and update your permalinks.

Comment: Great! Glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 0):

You need [Advanced Access Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-access-manager/) if you're willing to use plugin.

```
Filter Admin Menu
Filter Admin Panel
Filter Dashboard Widgets
Filter Metaboxes
Manage Comments
Manage Capabilities (Create, Delete)
Manage User Roles (Create, Edit, Delete)
Manage Access to your Posts, Pages or even Custom Post Types
Give possibility to promote Users
Manage Admin Menu Order
Manage other Administrators
Exclude Front-end Pages from Navigation
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create an rewrite rule pointing to your homepage or e.g. the first movie.
Here is exactly the thing you like to do, just the opposite: ;) 
http://www.ballyhooblog.com/custom-post-types-wordpress-30-with-template-archives/